# How to split camel-cased string by capitals but ignore acronyms

Tags: php

I want to sluggify a camel-cased string by breaking up the words by their capitals, like so:

```php
<?php
$classname = "MyBigClass";
$classname_arr = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $classname);
$slug = strtolower(implode("-",$classname_arr)); // outputs "my-big-class"
?>
```

But I don't want it to break up acronyms:

```php
<?php
$classname = "FAQList";
... // outputs "f-a-q-list", I want it to be "faq-list"
```

How do I accomplish this? I can't find any relavant SO question-answers.

Comment: you need smth like a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: this seems to work: `(?<![A-Z])(?=[A-Z])` - __EDIT__: not yet fully. It splits at the beginning also. __EDIT2:__ as your original regex does...

Comment: Problem with the concept - one letter words, eg  `youHaveAProblem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

although @Wee Zel's answer is allready accepted (and for good reason) I wanna give an extention, that also works for cases like `MyFAQ`:

```
<?php
$classname = "MyFAQ";
$classname_arr = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])|(?<![A-Z])(?=[A-Z])/', $classname);
$slug = strtolower(implode("-", array_filter($classname_arr))); // outputs "my-faq"
echo $slug;
```

I just combined my first try in comments (a negative lookbehind) with Wee Zel's lookahead.

*EDIT*:

here's with some test cases. only the last one might not be what we want.

```
<?php
$classnames = Array("MyFAQ", "myFAQ", "FAQList","myClassName", "youHaveAProblem", "MyClassNNName");

function splitCamelCase($classname) {
   $classname_arr = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])|(?<![A-Z])(?=[A-Z])/', $classname);
   $slug = strtolower(implode("-", array_filter($classname_arr))); // outputs "my-faq"
   return $slug;
}


foreach($classnames as $classname) {
    echo splitCamelCase($classname)."<br>\n";
}

// output:
// my-faq
// my-faq
// faq-list
// my-class-name
// you-have-a-problem
// my-class-nn-name
```

Comment: Hmm, thinking through this... "split by [uppercase character followed by non-uppercase letter] or [uppercase letter not preceded by uppercase letter]". Trying to think of how this might break.

Comment: yeah, it's a bit of a quirx, but passes most tests.

Comment: passes the 4 tests: MyBigList; FAQList; MyFAQ and youHaveAProblem - so an upvote from me :)

Comment: Okay, I just threw a whole bunch of scenarios at it and it works beautifully. Thanks to you both!!!

Comment: I would think `"MyClassNNName"` SHOULD spit out `my-class-nn-name`, as the lowercase letters after an uppercase indicates a separate word. It exceeds my needs at least, so I accept this'n.

Comment: "USofA" would spit out "u-sof-a" though, but that's just inconsistent capitalization rules, so it's still a pass.

Answer (score 3):

this checks for the next letter not being uppercase

```
$classname_arr = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/', $classname);
$slug = strtolower(implode("-", array_filter($classname_arr))); // outputs "my-big-class"
echo $slug;
```

note: using array_filter() to remove empty elements

Comment: sweet, it'sa working. Regex is so fun, innit? Oh, and good call on the `array_filter()`.

Comment: you got an upvote from me, because I used your solution for my extention!